# JQuery UI Widget Inheritance / class method call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-widget

I'm trying to write a custom widget in JQuery UI (v 1.9 m8): http://pastebin.com/zua4HgjR
From my site I call it like this: var D = new $.ui.mail({}); Basically it works.

Is there a better method to call doSend on button click?

The question is how to access object instance from function handler?
"this" returns entire html window.
Tried with $.proxy doesn't work: click: $.proxy(this.doSend, this);

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spending this weekend finally I finished my plugin: http://agrimarket-blacksea.com/jsc/jquery-mail.js

I decided to call "class function" in classical way: `$(this).mail('doSend')`, until I'll find something better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you setup the buttons by using the `options` member you'll have no reference to the element that you need in order to call `doSend`.  One workaround I was able to come up with is to assign the handler in the `_create` method where you have the appropriate reference.

```
_create: function() {
    this.options.buttons = [
        {
            text: 'Send',
            click: function(self) {
                return function() {
                    $(self.element).mail('doSend');
                };
            }(this)
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            click: function() { $(this).remove() }
        }
    ];                     
    this._super(arguments);
}
```

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/hhscm/2/

Comment: I made some test, seems that it works even defined in options: http://jsfiddle.net/JSNxh/1/ But I write some code in ExtJS and it was more simpler, just set scope of the function and it works. Here you need to write even class name. Proxy doesn't work... not so nice.